# How the IDE like eclipse knows that the loop is infinite?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, for-loop, ide

How the IDE like eclipse knows that there's an infinite loop and throws an exception for it?!...thank you in advance.

```
while(true)
{
}
```

Comment: By parsing the code.

Comment: The process is called [static program analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), per the Wikipedia article; ***Static program analysis** is the analysis of computer software that is performed without actually executing programs*.

Comment: Eclipse parses the code in to an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) and can then do the static program analysis.